# How to keep while(true) from blocking in Android

Tags: android, while-loop, blocking

I have a litle problem in my Android project.

I would like to do something every 1 second but the problem is that I have something else to do between those 1sec.

I tried to make a `while (true)` loop with `wait(1000)` inside but the problem is that this loop blocks all other instructions.

What would be a workaround / solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider a threading scenario. In case you are working with UI updates, you can use `postDelayed` so you can update your UI from withing the Runable. You can call the Runable from within a Runable, too.

```
View.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // do work
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Edit: Based on your comment, this is how you can implement calling back your function repeatedly.

```
public void PrendrePhoto() {
        String nom = "CameraPhoto";
        double x;
        camera = Camera.open();
        capteurBdd = new CapteursBDD(null);
        while (true) {
            camera.takePicture(null, null, null);
            x = 10;
            ValeursCapteur capteur = new ValeursCapteur(nom, x, 0, 0);
            capteurBdd.insertValeursCapteur(capteur);
            Log.i(null, "GPS = " + x);
            try {
                findViewById(R.id.mainView).postDelayed(predrePhotoRunnable, 1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            }
        }
    }

    private Runnable predrePhotoRunnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            PrendrePhoto();
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thank you for your answers, can you please give me more details abaut this, I am a beginer in android developping :-)

Here is the part of my code: 

`public void PrendrePhoto()  {
  String nom = "CameraPhoto";
  double x;
  camera = Camera.open();
  capteurBdd = new CapteursBDD(null);
  while (true){
  camera.takePicture(null, null, null);
  x=10;
  ValeursCapteur capteur= new ValeursCapteur(nom, x, 0, 0);
  capteurBdd.insertValeursCapteur(capteur);
  Log.i(null, "GPS = " + x );
  try {
          wait(3000);
      }
  catch(InterruptedException ex){                    
  }             
  }}`

Comment: See my Edit. For the `findViewById` you can use any control or layout.

Comment: Thank you so much Tomislave, but I have a problem on this line: `findViewById(R.id.mainView).postDelayed(predrePhotoRunnable, 1000);`

What is the mainView?

Thank you so much for your help

Comment: Oh sorry, it's ok, i writed: `findViewById(R.layout.main).postDelayed(predrePhotoRunnable, 1000);`

But now, I have a error on the `line catch (InterruptedException ex) {`

......

Comment: No, use `R.id.some_id_present_on_the_layout`. Do not use R.layout. The method `postDelayed` is present on the class `View`, so findViewById must return a View. Just use the id of any control (controls are called views in android) that is present on the activity.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [async tasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) in android.